# Printing file descriptors from PID in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux

So I have to print names of all the file descriptors of a certain PID. I know how to access it through the terminal navigating to `proc/[pid]/fd`, but all I get are colored numbers. I can get their name by writing `ls -l`.

---

My Question is how can I print these names in C. I tried using `stat`, but I couldn't get it to work, then I used `g_dir_open`. It didn't work aswell since i couldn't properly include `glib.h` (`"galloca.h not found in glib.h"`).

Thank you very much in advance,
Oh and please keep in mind that I'm a complete fool when it comes to linux.

Comment: *I'm a complete fool when it comes to linux.* Then maybe a little bit of research and effort on your part would go a long way. Show us a [MCVE] of what you tried.

Comment: `then I used g_dir_open` : great show us the code for this please.. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a combination of [`readdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) and [`readlink`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readlink) you can get the absolute paths of all your descriptors.  In this sample I use an arbitary pid, you can set it as a commandline argument or anyway you are calling the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *path = "/proc/3525/fd";
    DIR *fd_dir = opendir(path);

    if (!fd_dir) {
        perror("opendir");
        return 0;
    }

    struct dirent *cdir;
    size_t fd_path_len = strlen(path) + 10;
    char *fd_path = malloc(sizeof(char) * fd_path_len);
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * PATH_MAX + 1);

    while ((cdir = readdir(fd_dir))) {
        if (strcmp(cdir->d_name, ".") == 0 ||
            strcmp(cdir->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        snprintf(fd_path, fd_path_len - 1, "%s/%s", path, cdir->d_name);
        printf("Checking: %s\n", fd_path);
        ssize_t link_size = readlink(fd_path, buf, PATH_MAX);
        if (link_size < 0)
            perror("readlink");
        else {
            buf[link_size] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", buf);
        }
        memset(fd_path, '0', fd_path_len);
    }

    closedir(fd_dir);
    free(fd_path);
    free(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to skip the `.` and `..` directory entries in your `while()` loop, else they'll produce `EINVAL` errors from a failed call to `readlink()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You're right, that is worth a mention considering the example.  I edited in a `strchr` for `'.'`

Comment: Note that [`readlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlink.html) does not null-terminate its result string, but it does tell you how many characters were read.  (Yes, it's a bizarre piece of design!)  So, you need to capture the length and use that to either set the null byte (often the best choice) or use it with `printf("%.*s\n", (int)numbytes, buf);`, assuming you captured the length in `numbytes`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the heads up, I had a blindspot for that when going through the man-page.  Why do you think it was designed this way?

Comment: A plausible reason for the bizarre design of `readlink()` could be that the file system level doesn't keep null terminated strings (on the classic Unix file system with 14-character file name limit, the full length names were not null terminated, for example), so it wasn't considered convenient to null terminate them in the system call.  It barely qualifies as an excuse — it was still an asinine decision that a code review should have rejected.  However, it was also a decision made long in the past and frozen by standards and can't easily be changed now.

Comment: Incidentally, doesn't your `strchr(cdir->d_name, '.')` test skip any file name containing a `.` anywhere?  The normal test is `if (strcmp(cdir->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(cdir->d_name, "..") == 0) continue;` though you can optimize that if you wish.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The directory in question is a Linux `/proc/PID/fd` directory, so the only entries with a `'.'` character in the name will be the `.` and `..` ones.  Given that, the most efficient test would be `if ( cdir->d_name[0]=='.') { continue; }`